# use memcpy and begin() to copy a sub-array of a multidimensional array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, memory-leaks, memcpy, sub-array

I am trying to use memcy to copy an sub-array of an updated array A into an array B. Both A and B array have the same number of dimensions. The data going into array A is in the order of A.get_size(3) (Let's call dimension N here). Each update N will increase by 3(That means 3 set of data is added queueing in terms of dimension N). I need B to obtain the updated data (sub-array)only and the next copy will replace the previous 3. So I guess copy array A starting from (N-2) into B could do the job.

```
//initializing a new array B to obtain sub-array from A 
array B(A.get_size(0), A.get_size(1), A.get_size(2), 3, A.get_size(4));

//Get the forth dimension N 
N=A.get_size(3);

//copy the sub-array of A (from N-2 to N) into B(from 1 to 3 in dimension N)
memcpy(B.begin()+A.get_size(0)*A.get_size(1)*A.get_size(2)*(1)*A.get_size(4), A.begin()+A.get_size(0)*A.get_size(1)*A.get_size(2)*(N-2)*A.get_size(4), sizeof(T)*(A.get_size(0)*A.get_size(1)*A.get_size(2)*A.get_size(4)));
```

However, this could copy the number of elements but not the data value inside. Does it mean it gets memory leak? How should I make changes? Thanks!

Edited:
Thanks to the comments, I tried to use `std::copy` instead of `memcpy`, but this does not work in this case because the array A contain complex float. It gives this error when compiling,

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘copy(std::complex<float>*, const std::complex<float>*, long unsigned int)’
```

Anymore ideas except from using `std::copy`? Thanks!

Comment: use `std::copy` with `c++` containers, not `memcpy`

Comment: `memcpy` works in other .cpp files. So maybe its not the main solution. @RedAlert

Comment: Respect objects, std containers are non-trivial C++ classes whose memory model will get blown up by memcpy.

Comment: Using `memcpy()` in C++ is usually a bad idea.

Comment: The `array` type here is not `std::array`. There's very little anybody can say without some info about it. You need to provide a **minimal but complete** example that readers can try out.